# How to integrate a local SQLite database with jQuery mobile

Tags: android, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I am new to jQuery mobile. In my app I am displaying a html file using `webview`. I want to store the data in the local database. Generally we are using SQLite for storing the data in a local database, but here I am using jQuery mobile for the UI part. I am trying but I am not understanding how to access the data from html(jQuery mobile) and how to save that data in a local database.

Answer (score 0):

Usually web sites do not have the possibility to access the file-system - this is AFAIK also relevant for apps using the webview.

However you can implement the database access in the Java code part of your app and then expose a method of it that can be called by JavaScript within the webview.
You can expose a method by using the [addJavaScriptInterface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

An example how to use it can be found [here](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/) but it does not deals with SQLite access.

Answer (score 0):

This question has a list of available ORM libraries that you could use:

[What options are available for client-side JavaScript ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786307/which-javascript-orm-to-use)